# Extra whitespace on mobile version of website

Tags: html, css

I've trying to make a website just for a home project but having some trouble with the css for mobile.

There seems to be a lot of whitespace surrounding the elements to the right and bottom of the site. I'm newer to the world of CSS so any help would be appreciated.

[Screenshot of what chrome shows in developer mode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bkkw9.png)

```css
@media screen and (max-width:450px) {
    body {
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0 0 0 0;
        max-width: 100vw;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    html{scroll-behavior:smooth}

    .navbar {
        background-color: #008B8B;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 100;
        width: 100vw;
    }

    .navbar a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        float: center;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }

    .logo{
        display: none;
    }

    .loginLogo{
        width = 1px;
        height = 1px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .navbar-name{
        color: #f2f2f2;
        font-size:25px;
        padding-left: 25%;
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    }

    .navbar-home{
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        float: right;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .navbar-products{
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        float: right;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .navbar-about{
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        float: right;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .navbar-contact{
        font-size: 17px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-right: 17.5%;
        float: right;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    .navbar-login{
        font-size: 1px;
        padding-top: 1px;
        float: right;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    /* Change the color of links on hover */
    .navbar-home:hover {
        color: black;
    }
    .navbar-products:hover {
        color: black;
    }
    .navbar-about:hover {
        color: black;
    }
    .navbar-contact:hover {
        color: black;
    }
    .navbar-login:hover {
        color: black;
    }


    /* Add a color to the active/current link */
    .navbar a.active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }

    /*--------HOME PAGE------------*/

    .homePage{
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 820px;
        background-image: url(multiGrain.jpg);
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .homePageH1{  
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;    
        top: 26%;
        left:50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        font-size: 40px;
        color: white;
    }

    .homePageH2{
        position: absolute;
        text-align: center;
        display: inline;
        top: 28%;
        left: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        font-size: 20px;
        color: white;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
    }


    .aboutUsButton{
        position: absolute ;
        text-align: center;
        top: 31%;
        left:30%;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        background-color: rgb(0, 159, 159);
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .ourProductsButton{
        position: absolute ;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        display: inline-block;
        top: 31%;
        left:70%;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-right: 18px;
        padding-left: 18px;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
        background-color: rgb(0, 159, 159);
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: #f2f2f2;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /*-------ABOUT US PAGE----------*/

    .aboutUsPage{
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        height: auto;
        width: 100%;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .aboutUsH1{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: left;
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        top: 20%;
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        color: black;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }

    .aboutUsP{
        position: relative;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
        margin: 0px;
        text-align: left;
        float: bottom;
        display: block; 
        width: 90%;
        top: 5%;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
        color: black;
        background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    }

    .mixerImage{
        position: relative;
        object-fit: cover;
        width: 100%;
        height: 150px;
    }

    /*--------PRODUCTS PAGE------------*/

    .productsPage{
        position: relative;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: white;
        height: 300px;
        width: auto;
    }

    .productsH1{
        position: relative;
        text-align: left;
        top: 5%;
        left: 4%;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }

    .productsP{
        position: relative;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-top: 15px;
        text-align: left;
        float: inherit;
        width: 45%;
        left: 2%;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        color: black;
        background-color: white;
    }

    .productListButton{
        position: absolute ;
        text-align: center;
        left: 2%;
        padding: 10px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 25px;
        font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        color: white;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .slideshowImage1{
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        left: 55%;
        top: 15%;
        height: 100px;
        float: right;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); 
    }

    .slideshowImage2{
        width = 0px;
        height = 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    /*-------CONTACT US PAGE---------*/

    .contactPage{
        margin: 0 0 0 0;
        padding: 0px;
        background-image: url(rollingPin2.JPG);
        height: 700px;
        width: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-size: 200% 100%;

    }

    .contactH1{  
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;    
        top: 10%;
        left:0%;
        font-size: 70px;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Dancing Script', cursive;
    }

    .contactP1{
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        top: 10%;
        left:0%;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    }

    .contactP2{
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        top: 10%;
        left:0%;
        font-size: 18px;
        color: white;
        font-family: 'Slabo 27px', serif;
    }

    .contact-form{
        position: relative;
        top: 15%;
        width: 80%;
        left: 47.5%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }

    input[type=text], select, textarea {
      width: 100%; /* Full width */
      padding: 12px; /* Some padding */ 
      border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Gray border */
      font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
      border-radius: 4px; /* Rounded borders */
      margin-top: 6px; /* Add a top margin */
      margin-bottom: 16px; /* Bottom margin */
      resize: none; /* Allow the user to vertically resize the textarea (not horizontally) */
    }

    /* Style the submit button with a specific background color etc */
    input[type=submit] {
      width: 105%;
      background-color: #008B8B;
      color: white;
      padding: 12px 20px;
      border: none;
      border-radius: 4px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    /* When moving the mouse over the submit button, add a darker green color */
    input[type=submit]:hover {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .nameInput{
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        color: white;
    }

    .emailInput{
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        color: white;
    }

    .messageInput{
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
        color: white;
    }


    .submitButton{
        position: relative;
        top: 5px;
    }


    /*--------FOOTER---------*/

    .facebookLogo{
        width: 0%;
        height: 0%;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .footer {
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .footerp1{
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .footerp2{
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    .footerp3{
        width: 0px;
        height: 0px;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=yes">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Titillium+Web:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lobster&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dancing+Script&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Slabo+27px&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Doughboys Bakery</title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
</head>
<body>
    <header class="site-header">
        <nav class="navbar">
            <img class = "logo" src="Doughboys Logo - Website Version.png" alt="Logo" width="80"height="45.109">
            <a class="navbar-name" href="">Doughboy's Bakery.</a>   
                <a class="navbar-login" href="">Log In</a>
                <img class = "loginLogo" src="loginLogo2.png" onmouseover="this.src='loginLogo2Black.png';" onmouseout="this.src='loginLogo2.png';" width="50"height="28.889"/>
                <a class="navbar-contact" href="#contactPage">Contact</a>
                <a class="navbar-products" href="#productsPage">Products</a>
                <a class="navbar-about" href="#aboutUsPage">About</a>
                <a class="navbar-home" href="#homePage">Home</a>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <div class = "homePage" id="homePage">
        <h1 class="homePageH1">Quality or Quantity</h1>
        <h2 class="homePageH2">We're here to give you both</h2>
        <div class = "homePageButtons">
            <a class="aboutUsButton" href="#aboutUsPage">About Us</a>
            <a class="ourProductsButton" href="#productsPage">Our Products</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "aboutUsPage" id="aboutUsPage">
        <div class = "aboutUsText">
            <h1 class="aboutUsH1">Who we are.</h1>
            <p class="aboutUsP">Doughboys Bakery is a locally owned and operated wholesale bakery located near the city centre of Palmerston North. We produce traditional bakery goods like the classic Mince and Cheese Pies and Custard Squares. <br/><br/>We deliver actively in the Manawatu-Whanganui, Horowhenua & Wairarapa regions. (T's & C's Apply)<br/><br/>Use the contact section below to see how we can help suit your baking needs.</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "productsPage" id="productsPage">
            <h1 class="productsH1">What we make.</h1>
            <p class="productsP">At Doughboys' we supply traditionally sold bakery goods all the way from the classic Mince and Cheese Pie to the humble Scone.</p>
            <button class="productListButton" type="submit" onclick="window.open('ProductList.doc')">Full Product List</button>
            <div id="slideshow">
               <div>
                 <img class="slideshowImage1" src="fruitPies.jpeg">
               </div>
               <div>
                 <img class="slideshowImage2" src="pies.jpg">
               </div>
            </div>
            
    </div>

    <div class="contactPage" id="contactPage">
        <h1 class="contactH1">Contact Us.</h1>
        <p class="contactP1">ADDRESS: 15 Johnston St </p>
        <p class="contactP2">TEL: (06) 123 1234 | doughboys@gmail.net.nz</p>
        
        <div class = "contact-form">
            <form id = "contact-form" method="post" action="contactForm.php">
                <input class= "nameInput" type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your name...">
                <input class= "emailInput" type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Your email...">
                <textarea class= "messageInput" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Write something..." style="height:100px"></textarea>
                <input class= "submitButton" type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Doughboys-Bakery-Ltd-216199385212667">
         <img class = "facebookLogo" src="facebookLogo.png" >
        </a>
        <p class="footerp1">(06) 123 1234</p>
        <p class="footerp2">doughboys@gmail.net.nz</p>
        <p class="footerp3">15 Johnston St</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've just copied your HTML and CSS to a local page, and I can't reproduce the problem. Are you getting the problem with the exact code you've posted here?

Comment: do you have a hosted version? Because I can't even see the problem from the code you posted. Also, you have few mistakes in your CSS such as using `=` instead of `:`

Comment: the max-width of your media query is too small - try 650px, because I literally cannot shrink the browser window enough for your styles to come into effect